# How does twitter efficiently retrieve a user's tweet feed?

Tags: mysql, database, twitter, nosql

Let's say I was following 1000+ users. When I log into twitter I am shown a chronological list of tweets from the 1000 users I am following. How does twitter fetch these tweets.

I know they could do something like this:

```
select * from tweets where userID in (id_1,id_2,...,id_n) limit 50 order by time;
```

However, the 'in' clause can be really slow.

[how twitter works, does it use "in" to select tweets for followers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735498/how-twitter-works-does-it-use-in-to-select-tweets-for-followers?rq=1)

and

[Twitter like Model using SQL Server/Azure or Graph DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729082/twitter-like-model-using-sql-server-azure-or-graph-db)

say conflicting things, and the referenced links are old and dead.

So how does twitter efficiently get all the tweets from the people I follow?

Answer (score 1):

There's a [blog post](http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/12/19/how-twitter-stores-250-million-tweets-a-day-using-mysql.html) that goes in depth about Twitter's database infrastructure:

> When you tweet it's stored in an internal system called T-bird, which
>   is built on top of Gizzard. Secondary indexes are stored in a separate
>   system called T-flock, which is also Gizzard based. Unique IDs for
>   each tweet are generated by Snowflake, which can be more evenly
>   sharded across a cluster. FlockDB is used for ID to ID mapping,
>   storing the relationships between IDs (uses Gizzard). Gizzard is
>   Twitter's distributed data storage framework built on top of MySQL
>   (InnoDB).  InnoDB was chosen because it doesn't corrupt data. Gizzard
>   is just a datastore. Data is fed in and you get it back out again.  To
>   get higher performance on individual nodes a lot of features like
>   binary logs and replication are turned off. Gizzard handles sharding,
>   replicating N copes of the data, and job scheduling.  Gizzard is used
>   as a building block for other storage systems at Twitter.

It seems the first link you posted is correct, and the second is just suggesting a schema you *could* use to implement a Twitter-like database structure.

So, to answer your question, all tweets are stored in chunks based on the time they were tweeted and given unique IDs, which are indexed. Then, FlockDB manages relationships between IDs, i.e. the relationships that determine who's following who and who sees what Tweets.

Comment: All mentions of Twitter using FlockDB are atleast 2 or 3 yrs old. And FlockDB hasn't been updated in over 2 yrs, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FlockDB. Are there any posts that suggest Twitter is still using FlockDB in 2014 or if they've moved to something else.

Comment: @FrancisSnipe If you read Twitter's [blog post](https://blog.twitter.com/2013/new-tweets-per-second-record-and-how) from August 2013, it says that they moved to the Gizzard/Snowflake system for storage and it has met their needs. The infrastructure that they have been updating recently is the change from the Ruby VM to Java VM.

Comment: [This Quora answer](https://qr.ae/pKmbvn) describes how Twitter most likely stores and queries tweets efficiently `2. Store a user’s feed as an inbox; whenever a user posts something, send that content to the inbox of all of their followers`